# OpenCV Homogeneus blur slower than Gaussian blur?

Tags: java, android, performance, opencv, blur

I've run a performance test, that takes 1000 images in different resolutions and calculate time of calculation for both Gaussian Blur and Homogeneous Blur. What is curious to me, Gaussian blur is much faster than homogeneous with same kernel sizes.

Here is how calls look like:

```
int sizex = 3, sizey = 3;
Imgproc.blur(image, image2, new Size(sizex, sizey));
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(image, image2, new Size(sizex, sizey), 0, 0);
```

I'm testing it on Android device. Times are in microseconds. Version of OpenCV is 2.4.10.

[image: measurement]

What might cause this behaviour?

Comment: 1) `blur` is almost equivalent to `boxFilter`, not `GaussianBlur`. So different operations may take different time. 2) Perform the `GaussianBlur` on another image. e.g. `image3`. The difference may be due the fact that on the second call the image is already allocated.

Comment: @Miki Gaussian blur is one of the linear filters, that in theory should work the same way as Homogeneus/Box blur only with different values in kernel. Calls are only for demonstration of arguments. ```blur``` and ```GaussianBlur``` are independently called in two runs of a test (program execute). The images are same, but independently loaded for each call. Also I don't measure the time of an image loading/allecation (```Highgui.imread()```), only blur calls.

Comment: I was not referring to `imread`, but the allocation of  `image2`.  However, I got more or less similar results. Instead of `blur`, try using `filter2d`, with a kernel 3x3, with all values set to 1/9. It should be almost as fast as the gaussian kernel. The difference may also depend on the OpenCV version you're using, and if you have some optimization turned on, like tegra or ipp.

Comment: @Miki Using function ```filter2d``` with Gaussian kernel 3x3 is as slow as ```blur```, but box kernel 3x3 (with 1/9) is comparable to ```blur``` function. This still doesn't answer question why function ```GaussianBlur``` is about 10 times faster than ```filter2d``` and```blur```.

Comment: _This still doesn't answer question_  that's why mine was a comment and not an answer :D. I think all boils down to the fact that `GaussianBlur` use a separable linear filter engine inside, which iseems to be much faster than the box filter engine.

Comment: Actually, `boxFilter` is implemented as separable sum filter. So it's interesting why @Mati get such dramatic difference. It looks like CPU cache side effect. @Mati Could you please measure execution time separately for each function?

Comment: @akaraskov I can run a test and place it here, but define which one.

Comment: I too had faced this issue with GaussianBlur function on PC using OpenCV 3.0. I think the culprit is some GPU optimization step that moves the data between CPU and GPU, taking disproportionately long time compared to the actual processing. In my case, I had to turn the OCL flag to false: cv::ocl::setUseOpenCL(false) to solve the problem. I am not sure if a similar change could fix the issue here, but you could try.